# Using original 'new' operator instead of DEBUG_NEW

Tags: c++, debugging, memory-leaks

In order to collect memory leak on my debug tree I've added:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif
```

But I get a compilation error on the last line of:

```
void* AA::rpyCreateObject(void* addrs)
{
    if (addrs == NULL)
        return new AA;
    else
        return new(addrs) AA; // error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'addrs'
}
```

What I want this code to do is: the first new is DEBUG_NEW, and the second is the regular new.
Note - I CAN NOT use #undef new as this function is actually a macro:

```
#define ObjGenMacro(ClsName) void* ClsName::rpyCreateObject(void* addrs) { \
if (addrs == NULL) \
    return new ClsName; \
else \
    return new(addrs) ClsName; \
    }
```

How can this be done?

Comment: You're handling raw memory with `new` and _placement_ `new` and don't know how the preprocessor works ?

Comment: What is the problem to undef new?

Comment: This operation's code is actually a macro in a .h file- so I can not use preprocessor calls

Comment: Stefan - I'm not sure I understand your comment

Comment: Push new macro before this line, undef, returning original new, and pop it after this line.

Comment: The whole function is a define:  #define ObjGenMacro(ClsName) void* ClsName::rpyCreateObject(void* addrs) ... , So - I can not add prepsocessor calls there

Comment: #undef new before the macro and explicitly call DEBUG_NEW in your if

Comment: Thanks Drax - This will do the work, BUT - I use this macro in many files, so I dont want to change them all. Can I avoid it?